# Connect to netcat through telnet and shut down computer

Tags: bash, telnet, netcat

I'm using the following bash script to start listening to connections on port 8585. When connected by telnet and sending the text "shutdown" I would like the host computer to shut down. As of now I'm using my mac.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start listening on port 8585..."
while read line
do
    if [ "$line" == 'shutdown' ]; then
        # Execute shutdown now on the computer.
        break
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < <((echo "Welcome.") | nc -k -l 8585)
echo "Good bye"
```

When I try to connect to it through telnet I just get this as response:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Do any of you guys know why the connection gets closed straight away? Do you have any ideas?

I got the example code from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873788/bash-read-lines-from-netcat-connection#873794

Comment: check https://superuser.com/questions/1008348/netcat-keep-listening-for-connection-in-debian `-k` probably doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `(echo "Welcome.") |`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start listening on port 8585..."
while read line
do
    if [ "$line" == 'shutdown' ]; then
        # Execute shutdown now on the computer.
        break
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < <(nc -k -l 8585)
echo "Good bye"
```

Keep in mind that will only break the loop with the word `shutdown` but `nc` will continue listening